# Call C# WCF web service from Java using JAX-RPC

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wcf, jax-rpc

I have simple web service created with `C#`. Now I need to use this service from Java side in `JAX-RPC` style. I do java development using NetBeans. I add new web service to my project, paste WSDL URL dress, select destination package `calc` and `JAX-RPC` style. I have generated files:

```
CalculatorService.java
CalculatorService_Impl.java
CalculatorService_SerializerRegistry.java
```

How to use these classes to call service methods? In all these classes I don't see any methods I described in service. Where they are?

Web service code:

```
Form1 code:

    namespace CalculatorWCF
    {
        partial class Form1
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Required designer variable.
            /// </summary>
            private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

            /// <summary>
            /// Clean up any resources being used.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
            public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;


            public void startWCFCalculator()
            {
                if (serviceHost != null)
                {
                    serviceHost.Close();
                }

                // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and 
                // provide the base address.
                serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService));

                // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
                // listening for messages.
                serviceHost.Open();



            }


            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing && (components != null))
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }

            #region Windows Form Designer generated code

            /// <summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.SuspendLayout();
                // 
                // Form1
                // 
                this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
                this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(563, 446);
                this.Name = "Form1";
                this.Text = "Form1";
                this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
                this.ResumeLayout(false);

            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
```

Service code:

```
namespace CalculatorWCF
{


    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
        [OperationContract]
        double Add(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Subtract(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Multiply(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Divide(double n1, double n2);
    }

    public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {
        // Implement the ICalculator methods.
        public double Add(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 + n2;
            return result;
        }

        public double Subtract(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 - n2;
            return result;
        }

        public double Multiply(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 * n2;
            return result;
        }

        public double Divide(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 / n2;
            return result;
        }
    }


}
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>    <services>
      <!-- This section is optional with the new configuration model
           introduced in .NET Framework 4. -->
      <service name="CalculatorWCF.CalculatorService"
               behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service  -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="CalculatorWCF.ICalculator" />
        <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

CalculatorService.java

```
// This class was generated by the JAXRPC SI, do not edit.
// Contents subject to change without notice.
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, build R1)
// Generated source version: 1.1.3

package calc;

import javax.xml.rpc.*;

public interface CalculatorService extends javax.xml.rpc.Service {
}
```

CalculatorService_Impl.java

```
// This class was generated by the JAXRPC SI, do not edit.
// Contents subject to change without notice.
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, build R1)
// Generated source version: 1.1.3

package calc;

import com.sun.xml.rpc.encoding.*;
import com.sun.xml.rpc.client.ServiceExceptionImpl;
import com.sun.xml.rpc.util.exception.*;
import com.sun.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPVersion;
import com.sun.xml.rpc.client.HandlerChainImpl;
import javax.xml.rpc.*;
import javax.xml.rpc.encoding.*;
import javax.xml.rpc.handler.HandlerChain;
import javax.xml.rpc.handler.HandlerInfo;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class CalculatorService_Impl extends com.sun.xml.rpc.client.BasicService implements CalculatorService {
    private static final QName serviceName = new QName("http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples", "CalculatorService");

    public CalculatorService_Impl() {
        super(serviceName, new QName[] {

                    },
            new calc.CalculatorService_SerializerRegistry().getRegistry());
    }

    public java.rmi.Remote getPort(javax.xml.namespace.QName portName, java.lang.Class serviceDefInterface) throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {
        try {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceExceptionImpl(new LocalizableExceptionAdapter(e));
        }
        return super.getPort(portName, serviceDefInterface);
    }

    public java.rmi.Remote getPort(java.lang.Class serviceDefInterface) throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {
        try {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceExceptionImpl(new LocalizableExceptionAdapter(e));
        }
        return super.getPort(serviceDefInterface);
    }

}
```

CalculatorService_SerializerRegistry.java

```
// This class was generated by the JAXRPC SI, do not edit.
// Contents subject to change without notice.
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, build R1)
// Generated source version: 1.1.3

package calc;

import com.sun.xml.rpc.client.BasicService;
import com.sun.xml.rpc.encoding.*;
import com.sun.xml.rpc.encoding.simpletype.*;
import com.sun.xml.rpc.encoding.soap.*;
import com.sun.xml.rpc.encoding.literal.*;
import com.sun.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPVersion;
import com.sun.xml.rpc.wsdl.document.schema.SchemaConstants;
import javax.xml.rpc.*;
import javax.xml.rpc.encoding.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class CalculatorService_SerializerRegistry implements SerializerConstants {
    public CalculatorService_SerializerRegistry() {
    }

    public TypeMappingRegistry getRegistry() {

        TypeMappingRegistry registry = BasicService.createStandardTypeMappingRegistry();
        TypeMapping mapping12 = registry.getTypeMapping(SOAP12Constants.NS_SOAP_ENCODING);
        TypeMapping mapping = registry.getTypeMapping(SOAPConstants.NS_SOAP_ENCODING);
        TypeMapping mapping2 = registry.getTypeMapping("");
        return registry;
    }

    private static void registerSerializer(TypeMapping mapping, java.lang.Class javaType, javax.xml.namespace.QName xmlType,
        Serializer ser) {
        mapping.register(javaType, xmlType, new SingletonSerializerFactory(ser),
            new SingletonDeserializerFactory((Deserializer)ser));
    }

}
```

Comment: The methods marked with `[OperationContract]` are the ones exposed by the web service.

Comment: Yes, but where are these methods in java?